# Page Freezes When a4j:commandLink is Clicked After Clicking on h:commandLink

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

I have a jsf page with its backing bean. The page contain `h:form`with numerous input fields and buttons. The entire page is being submitted with `h:commandLink`, while there are several `a4j:commandLink` buttons as well. By clicking on `a4j:commandLink` button after the page has been submitted by `h:commandLink`, the page enters in "Loading, please wait" status indefinitely.

The page looks like:

```
<a4j:region>
    <rich:dataTable id="itemsTable" ...>
        <!-- richColumns-->

        <rich:column>
            <a4j:commandLink id="calculate_item" action="#{BackingBean.calculateItem}" value="Calculate" reRender="itemsTable">
                <f:param name="itemIndex" value="#{rowIndex}" />
            </a4j:commandLink>

            <a4j:commandLink id="delete_item" immediate="true" action="#{BackingBean.cleanItem}" value="Delete" reRender="itemsTable">
                <f:param name="itemIndex" value="#{rowIndex}" />
            </a4j:commandLink>
        </rich:column>

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <!-- richColumns-->

            <rich:column>
                <a4j:commandLink id="sum_all" styleClass="submit input-submit" action="#{BackingBean.calculateTotalSum}" value="Calculate Total" reRender="itemsTable" />
            </rich:column>
        </f:facet>
    </rich:dataTable>
</a4j:region>

<h:commandLink id="save" styleClass="submit" value="Save" action="#{BackingBean.save}" />
```

My BackingBean looks as follows:

```
public class BackingBean {

    // Fields and methods

    public void calculateItem() {
        // calculates
    }

    public void calculateTotalSum() {
        // calculates total
    }

    public String save() {
        boolean formIsValid = true;

        // do validations

        // save if the form is valid

        return formIsValid ? "success" : null;           
    }
}
```

- When I press on "Calculate" button or "Calculate Total" button everything works fine.
- When I press on "Save" button everything works fine (if the form has invalid fields (like required fields are empty), then validation messages are shown).
- When there are some invalid fields and I press "Save" button, then "Calculate" everything works fine.
- When there are some invalid fields and I press "Save" button, then "Calculate Total" the page falls into the page enters in "Loading, please wait" status indefinitely.

**The question is:** Why `a4j:commandLink` "Calculate" and "Calculate Total" behave differently and how to fix the problem with `a4j:commandLink` "Calculate Total" (what's wrong with it)?

**P.S.** Forgot to mention one thing: If I substitute

```
 <a4j:commandLink id="sum_all" action="#{BackingBean.calculateTotalSum}" value="Calculate Total" reRender="itemsTable" />
```

with

```
<h:commandLink id="sum_all" action="#{BackingBean.calculateTotalSum}" value="Calculate Total">
    <a4j:support reRender="itemsTable" event="" />
</h:commandLink>
```

everything works just fine with one limitation: all validation messages are being removed after button click.

Comment: Barev Armine, I'd guess the error is in your logic and your application crashes. Do you have any logs on the java-server side? if not: Try posting your logic inside the BackingBean

Comment: Check for javacript errors or http responses that contain errors,

Comment: @Kukeltje - there's no js code.

Comment: There is... a4j:* uses js behind the scenes... Better to first learn to understand the technology you use a little

Comment: No exception on server side, no errors on client side either.

Comment: My suggestion here is add a container in which your table and save button be in and your reRender attributes should point to this container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue.
 The reason was the css "submit" class which was used for "Calculate Total" button with "input-submit" class. I tried to find the exact attribute causing the issue but I couldn't. So a workaround solution was: to add a new css class: "audit-input-submit" which was a combination of the attributes of both "submit" and "input-submit" classes (excluding duplicates). After that the problem solved. Of course, if I could find the exact css attribute value which was causing the issue would be better.